# Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping'

Tags: android-studio

```
Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(
from=C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\FreshProject\app\libs\xerceslmpl-2.11.0.jar, 
to=C:\Users\Administrator\.gradle\caches\transforms-2\files-2.1\0b503c4af77ecb39244ba23ffbf08e5d\jetified-xerceslmpl-2.11.0.jar)'
```

I already done with `build.gradle` file to make changes in that in Dependencies.
Also tried Encoding changes in Settings.

Answer (score 6):

You've just deleted the jetified-xerceslmpl-2.11.0.jar file from the lib folder directly. 
Now you've to remove the jetified-xerceslmpl-2.11.0.jar file from the dependencies of the program too. So go on File - Project structure - Dependencies - under app find the "jetified-xerceslmpl-2.11.0.jar" and remove it from here. Now again run the project the error will not be there because you've also removed the jetified-xerceslmpl-2.11.0.jar from the file tree structure of your project.

[image]

You can also remove this decencies from the build.gradle file under the app directory of your project structure in the dependencies{ }

[image]

Hope this will help!!! 
Happy coding :)

Comment: my pleasure, Please don't forget to upvote it really helps  :)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced this same issue, What's my issue..
i have copied this 'additionnal.jar' file into app\libs folder
file name:- additionnal.jar

what i have written in build.gradle file(App level) to include:-
implementation files('libs/addtional.jar')

you can see that file name difference additionnal != addtional

hence i changed
implementation files('libs/additionnal.jar')

and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Create a directory named **libs** in your project if it's not present. In your case this will be `C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\FreshProject\app\libs`

Download this file [xerceslmpl-2.11.0.jar](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JarDownload/xerces/xerces-xercesimpl-2.11.jar.zip) and extract jar file and put jar file to **libs** directory that is
`C:\Users\Administrator\AndroidStudioProjects\FreshProject\app\libs`

Try rebuilding your project and it should work.