# Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping' in Android studio

Tags: android-studio, jakarta-mail

Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping(from=/home/alamin/Database/Automail/app/libs/additional.jar, to=/home/alamin/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/5c80954b8617a057a166d4547256bdee/jetified-additional.jar)'

I have added 'additional.jar' in libs folder and have added this dependency in build.gradle

> implementation files('libs/additional.jar')

I have also try this solution form this question: 
[Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534430/cannot-open-a-library-at-filemapping)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've just deleted the jetified-additional.jar file from the lib folder directly. Now you've to remove the jetified-additional.jar file from the dependencies of the program too. So go on File - Project structure - Dependencies - under app find the "jetified-additional.jar" and remove it from here. Now again run the project the error will not be there because you've also removed the jetified-additional.jar from the file tree structure of your project.

[image]

Hope this will help!!! Happy coding :)

I also answered this here [Cannot open a library at 'FileMapping'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57534430/cannot-open-a-library-at-filemapping/58881611#58881611)

Comment: Please be sure you're using the latest [JavaMail for Android](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/Android).